# ClojureScript equivalent for this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I am trying to use [esrecurse](https://github.com/estools/esrecurse) in my ClojureScript code, I have a working JavaScript snippet that looks like this

```
esrecurse.visit(ast, {
  Literal: console.log
});
```

and I'm trying to come up with the equivalent for ClojureScript, but whenever I run it `esrecurse.visit` is not called

```
#(.visit esrecurse % (js-obj "Literal" (fn [node] node)))
```

where `%` is the AST. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong honestly, I've also tried passing the second argument in a different way, like

```
#(.visit esrecurse (first (vals %)) {:Literal (fn [node] node)})
```

without success.

I'm invoking `mutate?` like this

```
(defn mutate?
  "applies a mutation to the ASTs,
  returns the mutated, or non mutated, ASTs"
  [asts]
  (map
   #(.visit esrecurse % #js {:Literal print})
   asts))

(mutate? (reader/to-ast (reader/read "./test/example-project/lib")))
```

But with both this version and mine I still don't get anything, I also tried passing `identity` instead of `print` but I just got `(nil)` as result.

Comment: If `esrecurse` is available globally then I believe you need to specify it as `js/esrecurse`

Comment: I imported it above that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me with a mocked implementation of `esrecurse.visit`.

```
(defn visit [ast]
  (.visit esrecurse ast #js {:Literal print}))

(visit #js {:type "Literal"})

;; prints #js {:type "Literal"}
```

And the mocked code:

```
var esrecurse = {
  visit(node, visitor) {
    visitor.Literal(node);
  }
}
```

Here's a less verbose version of the same idea.

```
 #(.visit esrecurse % #js {:Literal print}))
```

Verify that you're calling the function correctly, because your first implementation looks fine to me and works in place of either of the above functions.

At a guess, I'd say the reason you're not seeing anything happen in your second example is because Clojure's sequences are *lazy*—meaning your computation won't be applied until you ask for the result.

These lazy sequences (`take` returns one too) are only evaluated when something calls `doall`, `dorun` or `doseq` on them.

This happens under the hood if you call `print` or evaluate an expression which returns a lazy sequence in a repl.

You can try forcing the evaluation of your lazy expression with `doall`.

```
(doall
  (mutate? (reader/to-ast (reader/read "./test/example-project/lib"))))
```

This doesn't feel natural and that's the point. As a reasonably pure functional programming language, Clojure expects you to mostly write functions without side effects.

This is an example of where JavaScript interop can be painful, as `esrecurse.visit` doesn't actually return a value, making the call to `map` return a sequence of `nil` values. I would be tempted to pull the anonymous function out and redefine it to always return the AST it was passed.

```
(defn visit [ast]
  (.visit esrecurse ast #js {:Literal print})
  ast)

(defn mutate?
  "applies a mutation to the ASTs,
  returns the mutated, or non mutated, ASTs"
  [asts]
  (map visit asts))

(doall
  (mutate? (reader/to-ast (reader/read "./test/example-project/lib"))))
```

And just as a heads up, `mutate?` would be the convention for naming a function which returns a boolean. Maybe you meant `mutate!` instead, which would be the convention for a function that may perform side effects?

Comment: Hey Dan thanks for your answer! I tried your solution but still without results, I've edited my question with more informations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! In the end I was assuming I was passing a certain data structure, but `esrecurse` was receiving another one, hence my problem. Your answer helped a lot in isolating the error :)